# How can I use "resolve" with AngularJS routes to get data for my $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to use `resolve` in my AngularJS application's routes to retrieve data from my RESTful API and set it on my `$scope`.

I've tried the following to no avail -- `$scope.forms` is not being set:

```
angular.module('mycompany.resources').factory('Forms', ['$http', function($http) {
    var Forms = {};

    Forms.all = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/forms.json')
    };

    return Forms;
}]);

angular.module('mycompany.admin.forms', ['mycompany.resources']);
angular.module('mycompany.admin.forms').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/forms', {
            controller: 'formListController',
            templateUrl: 'forms/formList.html',
            resolve: {
                forms: ['Forms', function(Forms) {
                    return Forms.all()
                        .success(function(response) {
                            return response;
                        })
                        .error(function() {
                            return false;
                        });
                }]
            }
        });
}]);

angular.module('mycompany.admin.forms').controller('formListController', ['$scope', 'Forms', function($scope, Forms) {
    'use strict';
}]);
```

and my template:

```
<div ng-controller="formListController">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li ng-repeat="form in forms">
            <a class="form" href="#/forms/{{form._id}}">
                <span class="title">{{form.title}}</span>
                <span ng-if="form.lastPublished">Last published {{form.lastPublished | date:'M/d/yy'}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this  return Forms.all() is enough if there is an error the route is not set

Comment: Also, try injecting 'forms' into your controller (small f) and assign $scope.forms = forms.  Might want to change the name to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test this out, but the biggest problem seems to be that you're not
injecting the value into your controller.

So, just return `Forms.all()` from your `resolve` function, since it's already
returning a promise.  Then inject the value into your controller. Also, consider
changing the name to avoid ambiguity.

```
angular.module('mycompany.resources').factory('Forms', ['$http', function($http) {
    var Forms = {};

    Forms.all = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/forms.json')
    };

    return Forms;
}]);

angular.module('mycompany.admin.forms', ['mycompany.resources']);
angular.module('mycompany.admin.forms').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/forms', {
            controller: 'formListController',
            templateUrl: 'forms/formList.html',
            resolve: {
                forms: ['Forms', function(Forms) {
                    return Forms.all();;
                }]
            }
        });
}]);

angular.module('mycompany.admin.forms').controller('formListController', ['$scope', 'Forms', 'forms', function($scope, Forms, forms) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.forms = forms;
}]);
```

From the Angular documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider):

> `resolve` - `{Object.<string, function>=}` - An optional map of dependencies
>   which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are
>   promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be
>   rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are
>   resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and
>   `$routeChangeSuccess` event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the
>   `$routeChangeError` event is fired. The map object is:
>
> - `key` – `{string}`: a name of a dependency to be injected into the
>     controller.
> - `factory` - `{string|function}`: If string then it is an alias
>     for a service. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return
>     value is treated as the dependency. **If the result is a promise, it is
>     resolved before its value is injected into the controller.** Be aware that
>     `ngRoute.$routeParams` will still refer to the previous route within these
>     resolve functions. Use `$route.current.params` to access the new route
>     parameters, instead.

Comment: Thanks man! This worked. Also note that I needed to remove `ng-controller="formListController"` from my template.